# GLSL tapered lines

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, lines

I'm drawing lots of GL_LINES primitives, shading them using vertex and fragment shaders written in GLSL. What I'd like is for the lines to taper off at the ends in alpha value. That is, at the centre of the line the alpha value should be 1 but at each end it should taper off to 0.

I'm wondering if there is a nice solution that doesn't involve breaking the lines into several vertices first. That is, something done purely using shaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just pass a value to each vertex in the line. 0 for the start, 1 for the end. Let the interpolator interpolate between them, and then take the absolute distance of this value from 0.5 as 1 minus the alpha. Or, in GLSL:

```
gl_FragCoord.a = 1 - (abs(value - 0.5) * 0.5);
```

Where `value` is the value passed from the vertex shader. To do this, you can't render a `GL_LINE_STRIP` or `GL_LINE_LOOP`; it has to be `GL_LINES`.

Comment: that's close to what I ended up doing. A better function would be: `gl_FragCoord.a = 1.0 - pow(abs(2.0*value - 1.0),3.0);`